# Generating a time-varying Gaussian Process

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, gaussian

I'm trying to generate a Gaussian Process that changes over time. Generating a static GP is [easy enough](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html), but I'm not sure how to make it change over time.

One idea I have is to iterate over my discretized time and constantly create a new GP with a modified mean/covariance.

Is there a more efficient/elegant solution? An out-of-the-box solution would be especially useful, as would be the ability to generate multiple (overlapping) GP's that can be sampled at once.

Comment: Will your audience know what GP is they only see the title? Maybe it means "gross profit", for example

Comment: @SethDifley good point, edited title for clarity

Comment: @Teknophilia What is the definition of "a Gaussian Process that changes over time"?

Comment: If the norm and scale of the distribution are time-dependent but the process remains otherwise Gaussian, why can't you just multiply by a time-dependent scale and add a time-dependent offset to each sample you return?

Comment: @Stelios I'm looking for something similar to how a plume disperses over time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_dispersion_modeling#Gaussian_air_pollutant_dispersion_equation

Comment: @FrankM I think what you are describing is what I proposed as a possible solution in my question. I'm just not sure if there is a cleaner or more robust solution that that.

Comment: I don't see what's not robust about scaling and shifting the samples you get from a single distribution. As for sampling from multiple distributions, it doesn't make any difference: Samples from different distributions "should" be as uncorrelated as samples from the same distribution!